# ¿Cómo hago un mensaje de alerta en genexus?

Tags: genexus

Ejemplo si un botón hace cambios decir un mensaje "Datos eliminados correctamente"?

alguien que me ayude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende un poco en qué objeto estás, suponiendo es un webpanel, puedes usar la función "msg".
Ejemplo algo como:

```
event "borrar"
    // aca se borran los datos
    msg("Datos eliminados correctamente")
endevent
```

Si es una transacción hay una rule análoga (msg).

Más info: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31635,Msg%20function
Acá habla del "error viewer" para controlar el diseño de esos mensajes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.